# Time field not available

Tags: entities, feeds, importing-exporting

I'm trying to set up a CSV import to create nodes. On the Mapping page for the feed import, several of the fields in my target node type are not listed in the dropdown box to select as a target field. I don't know why.

Some info:

All the fields that aren't showing up are of type Time, added by the cck_time module. I've not seen any specific issues with mapping this field type, but it does seem like the common denominator here.

I set up the feed, then added extra content fields. The fields that aren't showing up were all added at this later point, although others that were added at the same time are. I've flushed cache several times.

Several of the fields share the same label (ie: "Earliest booking"), although obviously not the same machine name. (For instance, there's one "Earliest booking" field for each weekday, and the field is nested inside a group for that weekday). Other fields that share identical labels are showing up in the Mapping dropdown.

The feed isn't Attached to the content type (under Basic Settings), it uses a standalone form. It uses a Node processor and the selected Bundle is the content type.

Any ideas? Why would a content field not show up in that Mapping dropdown? Have I missed some vital step?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution @ https://www.drupal.org/node/2085879

Where you can use the patch by agileadam @ https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/timefield_feeds_support-2085879-6_7.x-1.0-alpha2.patch

On top of which you can also apply a patch from pontus.froding found @ https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/0001-adds-weekly-repeat-to-times.patch which also as an added bonus adds the weekday repeating to the import

The patch is still to this date not imlemented into any release and the issue of time field not showing up in feeds was that Feeds doesn't know the field type and the Timefield module didn't have any feeds hooks in it, to make feeds module aware of it.

Implementing this patch manually (for now) seems to be the only solution.